# Docker container called in Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

How do I call a docker container within Laravel? I am using the following package to download PDFs https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/browsershot, I have an npm container which I am trying to use with this package.

My site container doesn't have node or npm installed which is why I need to use my npm container instead.

Here is my docker file

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: odc
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ".d3aP/7N,c)&^EdC"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "%3h_Ssxm7sSj#bw!"
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/composer/Dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel

  chrome:
    image: zenika/alpine-chrome:latest
    container_name: headless-chrome
    networks:
      - laravel
    command: [chromium-browser, "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox", "--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"]
```

Here is the code I am trying to use with Browsershot to point to my npm container

```
Browsershot::html($html)
    ->setIncludePath('npm')
    ->setNodeModulePath("npm")
    ->setChromePath('chrome')
    ->noSandbox()
    ->showBackground()
    ->format('A4')
    ->savePdf($path . '/portrait.pdf');
```

As you can see I am using the `->setIncludePath('npm')` to try and call my npm container but I am still receiving this error when I try and run this code

`sh: npm: not found sh: node: not found`

Comment: you are mixing things... so your php laravel container HAS NO access to the file system of your node container by default. So that saying in your laravell container there will be no npm installed at all... If you want to make use of the npm bins from that other container in your php container you have to mount it. But i would not recomand that... why not simply install node / npm in your php container?

Comment: @TimoStark as you can probably tell I am really new to docker, I'm just unsure on the best practises. If I install npm / node on my php container should I remove the npm container?

Comment: @TimoStark why you don't recommend to create an own container for npm/nodejs? From my point of view, it makes the whole CI/CD process better. If you have npm/nodejs/chrome inside the Laravel container will make your image bigger than neccessary i think. I guess you have to deploy the Laravel container more often because of changes on your code and therefore it makes sense to seperate the node stuff (because changes are less often there) to keep the Laravel image small. Wouldn't that result in less time in k8s pipelines and deployments, copying images etc?

Comment: I am not in general against having a second container instance running to handle the node part. But in this special case we are not talking  about having two containers and the node container contains its own service that can be "called" from laravel. If the NodeJS Container is a service we can send a HTML payload over the Network and it would response with a PDF I would totally agree! But sharing the file system of two containers (no matter if k8s or not) is not a ideal solution. From my point of view the NodeJS app is part of the Service written in Laravel. So it should be part of the Contai

Comment: But again: Given in this scenario the PDF-Service would be a "real" service and not just a container that holds the npm binary I would totally agree with you! Having that in seperate service / Container is a good idea. Maybe its worth refactoring this implementation one day and make a real PDF-Rendering Service out of it. I did that several times without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a seperate Node / NPM Container. The Browsershot is part of your applications core. To make it work you need nodejs and npm. That saying I would construct my own container image incuding PHP and Node. That makes the implementation of Browershot more simple.

If neede you can split them up later. But in that case I would create a new BrowserShot service (PHP + Node).

As you can see, there are multiple ways doing it.

What about using NGINX Unit for your applications container base? You could use the Unit PHP base image and add node on top of it.

I did that here:

https://github.com/nginx/unit-examples/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx/unit:1.22.0-php7.3
RUN mkdir /var/apphome/ && groupadd -r appuser && useradd --no-log-init -r -g appuser appuser && \
    chown -R appuser:appuser /var/apphome/ && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y gnupg && \
    curl -sL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://packages.nginx.org/unit/debian/ buster unit" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unit.list && \
    echo "deb-src https://packages.nginx.org/unit/debian/ buster unit" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unit.list && \
    apt update && apt install -y unit-dev npm php7.3-mysql php7.3-gd && \
    npm install -g --unsafe-perm unit-http -y

COPY src/ /var/apphome/app/
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /var/apphome/
COPY .unit.conf.json /docker-entrypoint.d/.unit.conf.json
CMD ["unitd", "--no-daemon", "--control", "unix:/var/run/control.unit.sock"]
```

Note! This is a demo purpose. You can adapt it for your production needs!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have installed npm onto my php container and it works, does this mean I should remove my external npm container?

Comment: Yes. Just delete it from your docker-compose file. Great it works for you. For later projects. First: Thnik simple and start simple. Complexity will come sooner then later by itself :D Happy Hacking!

Comment: Thanks, does this also apply to my chrome container? I wanted to create a separate container to host headless chrome and access it in my laravel project `->setChromePath('chrome')` I keep receiving an error saying it isn't found.

Comment: Same thing. Include it in your main php project. From an security point of view, do not use the webroot of your PHP application for each of those binaries. But you can safely include. As said you might want to create a seperate Browsershot service later and use cURL in PHP to call it. FOR EXAMPLE